# Horizontal SWF's giving white space

Tags: html, css, flash, actionscript-3

I'm unable to remove the white space between SWF's on a HTML page.

I know about using 'block' in the CSS, but as it's horizontal that doesn't seem to work. I've also added "0" for border to no avail. Going out of my wit here trying to solve this.

My HTML code:

```
    <div id="banner">           
    <div class="wrap">
        <div style=height:66px; align="center">
          <object id="FlashID" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="151" height="65" border="0">
            <param name="movie" value="images/flash_buttons/home_white.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
            <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
            <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
            <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="images/flash_buttons/home_white.swf" width="151" height="65" border="0">
              <!--<![endif]-->
              <param name="quality" value="high" />
              <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
              <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
              <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
              <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
              <div>
                <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
                <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
            </div>
              <!--[if !IE]>-->
          </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
          <object id="FlashID2" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="151" height="65" border="0">
            <param name="movie" value="images/flash_buttons/guide_green.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
            <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
            <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
            <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="images/flash_buttons/guide_green.swf" width="151" height="65" border="0">
              <!--<![endif]-->
              <param name="quality" value="high" />
              <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
              <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
              <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
              <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
              <div>
                <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
                <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
            </div>
              <!--[if !IE]>-->
          </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
```

and Screenshot:

http://www.hosted101.net/uploads/upload/1327873868428issues.png

Comment: Have you tried setting the margin and padding to 0 on your object tags?

Comment: Yes; that does nothing unfortunately.

Comment: Use SWFobject to embed your embed code doesn't look correct to me

Comment: SWFobject does not fix it. This embedding is the standard from Flash Publish.

Answer (score 0):

By default body element on HTML page have margin. Specify CSS:

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

inside your HTML document

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can not see your HTML page so I can not say real reason. There are several possible reasons for this blank space. Main: margin or padding for "object" HTML element or for its parent element, scale mode in which you embed swf into HTML. But without real example I not able to guess what is it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `line-height: 0;` for the container, might help you.

Answer (score -1):

To remove white space use  `wmode="transparent"` in HTML code. Here is an example.

```
<embed  src="imageurl.swf"  wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"quality="high" width="1020" height="600"  " >
```

Comment: Where is the `example`?